# Spring integration Unzip transformer throws ReplyRequiredException exception

Tags: java, spring-integration, compression, gzipinputstream

We would like to decompress a byte array using [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) and are experiencing the following exception upon using unzip-transformer:

> org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#1$child#1' ., and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.,failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[327] ...

This is the **.xml** blob we are trying to use for this effort:

```
int-zip:unzip-transformer result-type="BYTE_ARRAY" expect-single-result="true"/>
```

The equivalent java code using service-activator works fine for decompression:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream;
gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) 
message.getPayload()));
IOUtils.copy(gzipInputStream, byteArrayOutputStream);
byteArrayOutputStream.close();
return new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Is there any way to do the same code using unzip-transformer?

Comment: You need to share some simple application to reproduce the issue. Not clear right now what and how to do to get the same exception. Thanks for understanding

Comment: I built a spring application to reproduce this error:https://github.com/praveenKumar88/springproject  . You can reproduce this behavior by executing this test:https://github.com/praveenKumar88/springproject/blob/master/src/test/java/GzipUtilTest.java#L50 . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`GZIPInputStream` ... The Spring Integration ZIP doesn't support GZIP, only regular ZIP with entries. That's how you get that exception:

```
 if (uncompressedData.isEmpty()) {
                if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                    logger.warn("No data unzipped from payload with message Id " + message.getHeaders().getId());
                }
                unzippedData = null;
            }
```

Just because the `ZipUtil.iterate(InputStream is, ZipEntryCallback action)` has nothing to iterate over GZIP payload.

Comment: Hi Artem, Do you have any thoughts on a work-around for this? Would you say the best practice for dealing with this with spring integration is using service-activator and the java code mentioned above or is there a better way? Do you also foresee the gzip feature being implemented in future versions of spring?

Comment: Yes, service activator for custom code is the solution for now. I think we have an open issue fo gzip support there, but no plans when we come back for the fix. Contribution is welcome!

Comment: Can you please share the issue link? I would love to contribute towards the fix.